# How to encrypt a value in Node JS using node-rsa and decrypt the encrypted value using JSEncrypt in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, encryption, cryptography

The question may be silly. But I don't get any better documentation to solve the problem.

I am developing an app using `Node JS/ Express JS` in the back end  and `Angular JS/ JSEncrypt` in the Front End.

there is one field in the output JSON of every REST api named `totalSales`. I want this field to be encrypted when it comes from the backend using `node-rsa` module. And I am able to decrypt the value using `JSEncrypt` in the front end.

Front End I want to write code in the manner,

```
// pseudo code for front end    
this.crypt = new JSEncrypt({ default_key_size: 1024 })
    data['totalSales'] = this.crypt.decrypt(data['totalSales'])
```

Back end I want to write the code

```
//pseudo code for back end
 var key = NodeRSA(<some pem string if possible>)
```

But I get confused about `public/ private key`. 
How to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just use forge on both sides?